# Why is the 'Function Body' bottlenecking my application?

Tags: .net, vb.net, performance

The application I am developping runs too slowly.

I have run the performance diagnostics of Visual Studio, and found out that one single function was running 66% of the time, the `GetHashCode` function of the following class.

```
Public Class Identifier

    Public Property Name As String

    Public Overrides Function GetHashCode() As Integer
        Return Name.ToUpper().GetHashCode()
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function Equals(other As Object) As Boolean
        Dim otherIdentifier = TryCast(other, Identifier)
        If otherIdentifier Is Nothing Then
            Return False
        Else
            Return String.Equals(Name, otherIdentifier.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
        End If
    End Function
End Class
```

What puzzles me even more, is that in the 'Called functions' panel, I read, in terms of Elapsed Inclusive Time:

- System.String.ToUpper(): 0.61%
- System.String.GetHashCode(): 0.21%
- Function Body: 66.67%

Since the function is doing nothing but call the `ToUpper` and `GetHashCode` functions, I have a hard time figuring out what I can improve here.

Could you please help me shed some light on this?

Comment: This doesn't solve your issue, but you shouldn't compute the hash code on a mutable property.

Comment: If the issue is calling `GetHashCode` a large number of times on one object (vs. calling it once on a large number of objects) you might consider caching the result.  I've had an application where I got a ~50% performance improvement by doing this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with VS performance diagnostics. But [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/beginners-guide-to-performance-profiling?view=vs-2017) is something mentioned about the *Function Body*.

> `Function Body` also shows you the total amount of time (and the
>   percentage of time) spent in the function body excluding time spent in
>   calling and called functions

But it doesn't really explain why 2/3 of the time is spent in `GetHashCode` when the calls to `ToUpper` and `GetHashCode` are excluded.

However..

> "High values in Function Body may indicate a performance bottleneck
>   within the function itself"

That's obvious, `ToUpper` always has to create a new string for every string it has to compare. If you're doing that millions of times you have high memory pressure and the GC kicks in. Thats why i would use the `StringComparer`:

```
Public Overrides Function GetHashCode() As Integer
    Return StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase.GetHashCode(Name)
End Function
```

You can use it also in `Equals`

```
Public Overrides Function Equals(other As Object) As Boolean
   Dim otherIdentifier = TryCast(other, Identifier)
   If otherIdentifier Is Nothing Then Return False
   Return StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase.Equals(Name, otherIdentifier.Name)
End Function
```

Comment: Follow-up: Using `StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase.GetHashCode` solved this issue of the function body taking so much time in the profiler, which I used on a small sub-part of the application.

After implementation in production, the complete application runtime has been decreased by more than 60% :)